# Getting a Cast Exception

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I am using Linq 2 SQL and I am getting this error message when firing the button click event "Specified cast not valid", the stack trace is below. I am new to using linq to sql and trying to get away from ADO.NET, which it is working, by the way, using ADO.NET, calling a stored procedure.

> [InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid.]
>      System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBuffer.get_Decimal() +5299638
>      System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.GetDecimal(Int32 i) +68
>      Read_GetBreakDownsResult(ObjectMaterializer`1 ) +3730
>      System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.ObjectReader`2.MoveNext() +32
>      System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection) +381
>      System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList(IEnumerable`1 source) +58
>      GuhringWebsite2.ReportingPortal.Default.LoadBreakDowns(Object sender, EventArgs e) in c:\WillieDevonSmith\GuhringWebsite2\Reporting\Reports\Default.aspx.cs:51
>      System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e) +9628722
>      System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +103
>      System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +10
>      System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String eventArgument) +13
>      System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData) +35
>      System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +1724

Here is the code which calls the stored procedure using linq 2 sql, which I am passing in a static value for testing.

```
    ReportsDataContext reportsdbContext = new ReportsDataContext();

    var query = reportsdbContext.GetBreakDowns("0070917819");
    GridView1.DataSource = query;
    GridView1.DataBind();
```

In the designer.cs class it gets excuted here

```
    [global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.FunctionAttribute(Name="dbo.GetBreakDowns")]
    public ISingleResult<GetBreakDownsResult> GetBreakDowns([global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ParameterAttribute(Name="BillToCustomerNo", DbType="NVarChar(20)")] string billToCustomerNo)
    {
        IExecuteResult result = this.ExecuteMethodCall(this, ((MethodInfo)(MethodInfo.GetCurrentMethod())), billToCustomerNo);
        return ((ISingleResult<GetBreakDownsResult>)(result.ReturnValue));
    }
```

My Stored Procedure looks like this

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetBreakDowns] 
-- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
@BillToCustomerNo nvarchar(20)
AS
BEGIN
-- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
-- interfering with SELECT statements.
SET NOCOUNT ON;

-- Insert statements for procedure here
SELECT DivName,SUM(CASE WHEN BillingDateYY = '2010' THEN totalvalue ELSE 0 END) 
AS '2010',SUM(CASE WHEN BillingDateYY = '2011' THEN totalvalue ELSE 0 END) 
    AS '2011',SUM(CASE WHEN BillingDateYY = '2012' THEN totalvalue ELSE 0 END)
        AS '2012',SUM(CASE WHEN BillingDateYY = '2013' THEN totalvalue ELSE 0 END)
            AS '2013',SUM(CASE WHEN BillingDateYY = '2014' THEN totalvalue ELSE 0 END)   
                AS '2014', sum(totalvalue) FROM  [ReportData].[dbo].[Sales] WHERE BillToCustomerNo in (@BillToCustomerNo) 
                    GROUP BY DivName
UNION 
SELECT 'Total'As 'DivName',SUM(CASE WHEN BillingDateYY = '2010' THEN totalvalue ELSE 0 END) 
    AS '2010',SUM(CASE WHEN BillingDateYY = '2011' THEN totalvalue ELSE 0 END) 
        AS '2011',SUM(CASE WHEN BillingDateYY = '2012' THEN totalvalue ELSE 0 END) 
            AS '2012',SUM(CASE WHEN BillingDateYY = '2013' THEN totalvalue ELSE 0 END)
                AS '2013',SUM(CASE WHEN BillingDateYY = '2014' THEN totalvalue ELSE 0 END)
                    AS '2014',sum(totalvalue) FROM  [ReportData].[dbo].[Sales] WHERE BillToCustomerNo in (@BillToCustomerNo)
END
```

Comment: The information provided doesn't give any information for clues. May be if you can post the *resulting data* from manual execution of SP would help. The error you're getting is because in the data returned by SP have a particular column which might be containing null and the property it's trying to assign is non-nullable. Look for column type Price or anything that is having value of type Decimal.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure what your particular issue is,  but as a general tip be sure to wrap you the use of your DB  Context in a using statement. This helps insure that you DB context object will finalize and your db connection will close.

`using (ReportsDataContext reportsdbContext = new ReportsDataContext()) { //rest of code goes here }`

Comment: I think @vendettamit is on the right track. Is your Gridview a custom gridview? Meaning you are manually defining the columns? I bet one of the bound columns is expecting certain type and receiving another. Make sure your the types in your bound columns match the ones in your DB and check for nulls.

Comment: What is the type of `DivName`? (in the table and the C# model)